# python 3 - why does for loop not work when looking for maximum ord() value?

Tags: python-3.x

```
text = "NǆƆΌŮýƤ¨ǿȢÛʉ̣ƍǹƭɴͩˍΒŶØǝƸ͕˛Ǒä¨ØˤΆ˩Ųȇʟϋº"
def maxOrd(text):
    for k in text:
        k = max(range(ord(k)))
        
    return k
```

want to get the maximum unicode value, but the loop returns the uni value of the first char only

Comment: Why is there range? Is it needsd

Comment: `max(range(n)) == n-1`... did you mean `k = max(ord(char) for char in text)`?

Comment: sandbox this q => https://edube.org/sandbox/b9676c86-2809-11eb-b2f5-024250c4691c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is

```
text = "ACB"
def maxOrd(text):
    mx = -1
    for k in text:
        mx = max(ord(k), mx)
    
    return mx

print(maxOrd(text)) # output is 67 - letter C
```

Comment: exactly what i needed, mind explaining why wasn't my code working? thanks in advance

Comment: @wylde `range(x)` gives the `iterable` that iterates through `0` to `x`. You were trying to get the max of that each iteration (which is x-1) and assign it to `k`. After the loop, last value of k is the max of the `range(ord(last_letter))` - which is 1 less than the `ord(last_letter)`

Answer (score 0):

Your `for loop` was not working because you were only returning the maximum value in the range 0 to n-1, where n is the `ord` of that character. Remember, `range` does not include the last value. You can verify this by printing `print(list(range(5)))`, which only returns 0 to 4, **not** 5. You also then calculate the `max` of that range, which will always be the last value in the range. Furthermore, you say `return mx` after the loop has ended, or, reached the last character of `text`. You never really calculate the maximum out of the entire string of text. I see there is a marked answer, but I want to offer another solution:

```
def max_ord(text):
    return max(map(ord, text))
```

`map` applies a function to iterables. We can then just simply pass in `ord` as the function and `text` as the iterable. Then, wrap it in `max` to find the largest value.

Comment: thank you very much, simple yet elegant, never thought of it that way

Comment: No problem, I hope it helps!